# Get form source file at runtime from external process in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winapi, pinvoke

I am currently working in a very large solution (120+ projects). Very often, we need to find a particular form in a large desktop application, consisting of hundreds of forms.

For example, we might have a requirement to edit some controls on a certain form.

We don't know the form name, but we know how to navigate to the form when running the application.

In order to identify a form, we currently try to find some unique text on the form, and then search all the source files for this string. That's not very cool.

Instead, I'd like to make a little tool that can identify the source file for a form, or at least the name property of the form object.

We can't add code to the solution itself, so we will have to make an external exe.

I am not sure if this is even possible. I am thinking it might be possible through reflection, but I'm no expert on the matter.

If anyone have ideas as to how to solve the problem, that would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Doing this out-of-process makes very little sense and makes this task unnecessarily difficult.  If you don't own the app then state so in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used [Managed Spy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163617.aspx) for this. It displays a treeview of controls in your .NET-based client application.When you select a control, the PropertyGrid shows properties on that control.
[image]

Comment: Thanks Jacob. On a first quick look, it seems exactly like what I am looking for. I'll do some tests tomorrow, to verify.

Comment: Just a quick note: Managed spy doesn't seem to work with framework 4.0, but all earlier frameworks work fine. As it's open source, it's probably possible to make it work with 4 as well, with a little effort.

Comment: An alternative solution that's inspired by Managed Spy, but works fine with 4.0: .NET Object Spy (download from  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/objectspy.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Morten,

I'm a nasty hacker... I had the same problem (more or less), so I setup a hidden double-click-point on the main form which (in #if DEBUG only) closed the database connection, so the next access would crash. Then in VS I just set "break on any exception" double-click-just-there, do a "submit", and TADA, it shows me where-the-hell-in-this-bluddy-confusing-world am I. A stack trace would do just as well.

Cheers. Keith.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Keith, sounds indeed like a really nasty hack, love it :-) Was thinking of doing something like this with a keyboard hook or similar. But alas, Jacob is right, we can't add code to the solution, at least not for something like this.

Comment: Morten, remember that it only effects Debug mode... it simply isn't there in the Release build. BTW: We've also got a click-point to login (in debug-mode only) which reads credentials from HKCU. Right now, I'm thinking about extending that to Robo-controll the GUI using (http://java.net/projects/jemmy/, or something like it) to expedite the highly repetitious steps getting the GUI to the place/state you need to even start testing YOUR changes; all from an invisible double-click point on the login form. Convenient!

Comment: Indeed very convenient. I don't know Jemmy, but if you are looking aruond at different options, you could also try looking into Sikuli script. It's a kind of visual scripting language, which is super cool and easy to work with. You can set up auto-gui control for any app, in a very short time span. Anyways thanks for your suggestion, if the Managed Spy app doesn't work out, I'll try to convince the higher ups to allow me a little bit of #if debug :-)

Answer (score 0):

Some Automated test tools will give you a lot of info about a running form.
Basically all the properties of the control itself.

In our company we use CodeComplete.

However that is a tool that must be bought, you may search for some smilar free.